# Casting, performance, error handling

Tags: c#, performance, error-handling

I have 3 ways in which I could do this

```
JToken jEmail = jObject["emails"];
```

```
email = (string)jEmail["preferred"];
```

or

```
email = jEmail["preferred"].ToString();
```

or

```
email = jEmail["preferred"] == null ? null : (string)jEmail["preferred"];
```

So safely doing error handling is  null or empty string, vs. performance...   what is the preferred of the 3 above???

Comment: The preferred is to not do premature optimization. Choose what works, then improve the performance if necessary. Do not improve the performance if _not_ necessary.

Comment: All 3 "work" - I just wanted to go with what is standard

Comment: The standard is to not worry until you have to, all else being equal.

Comment: You are working with JObject, I gather from azure mobile services,  it is fairly forgiving with errors... all this is just json string... so casting is fairly benign!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three examples have three different behaviors. Depending on which behavior you want, you should take the one that works:

1. `email = (string)jEmail["preferred"];`

   I'm not certain, but I believe this will throw a `NullReferenceException` if "preferred" is missing. You might get away with it since `string` is a reference type. This would certainly fail if you were casting to `int`, for instance. See my comment on #3.
2. `email = jEmail["preferred"].ToString();`

   This will *definitely* throw a `NullReferenceException` if "preferred" is missing, as you can't do `null.ToString()`.
3. `email = jEmail["preferred"] == null ? null : (string)jEmail["preferred"];`

   This will work either way. Be aware that callers may assume that `email` is never null, in which case they may throw `NullReferenceException` when trying to access it.

Choose which behavior you want, then implement it. Don't do it for performance, though, since you have no idea at this point whether you will be improving performance. Performance tuning must be done by *measuring* performance, and only then *tuning* it.

Comment: Yes....  1. or 3. ... really depends on quality and integrity of the data, this is the JSON ... JObject stuff... so completely how you would receive the windows live credentials from azure mobile services after the node.js was used along with adding the extended scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the above answer -  I agree with.

This is benign in nature from JObject  ....  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject  / .JToken ...0

```
email = (string)jEmail["preferred"];
```

However, you are welcome to use the ternary of below

```
 email = jEmail["preferred"] == null ? null : (string)jEmail["preferred"];
```

Not sure you will gain anything.  You will end up with carpal tunnel as it appears not necessary, but depends on your end goal.

Performance... don't worry about it in this issue.